# Extreme point of $B_A = \{a\in A: \|a\| \leq 1\} $ in a Banach algebra $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've  send  this question a little while ago now I edit it

Let $A$ be a  Banach algebra with identity  $e_A$

> prove that $e_A$ is an  extreme point of $B_A = \{a\in A: \|a\| \leq 1\} $

Recall that $x$ is an extreme point of $B_A$ if $x = \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2\in B_A$ implies that $x= x_1=x_2.$

**My attempt:**
 $x,y \in  B_A$, $t\in (0,1)$ and  $e_A=tx+(1-t) y$

it is easy to see that
$$\|x\|=\|y\|=1$$
therefore $$\|e_A-tx\|=\|(1-t) y\|<1  {\text{and }}\|e_A(1-t) y\|=\|tx \|<1$$

this implies that $$tx, (1-t) y \in Inv A$$
where $Inv A$ is the set of all invertible elements of $A$

I can't continue from here